# ipython3 and jupyter notebook not allowing python3 opition

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Okay, I know I am probably going to receive a cluster of down votes after having been unable to solve this issue, but I am fairly new to python and jupyter notebook. So far I have only been able to use python3 with jupyter notebook once upon initial set up and ever since then it has defied all logic and despite ipython being the backend of jupyter notebook, stating it no longer supports python2 like some progressive and want's nothing to do with pyhton2 anymore; python2 is bunked down in my notebook like the Russians at Stalingrad and I fear I may not be able to drive the Bolshevik out.

So like a good little boy I make my own venv environment and try and install ipython for python3 [you know - the only version that matters according to their website]:

```
    main@McCarter:~/Desktop
    $ sudo python3 -m venv /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas
    main@McCarter:~/Desktop
    $ source /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/bin/activate
    (Intro-to-Pandas) main@McCarter:~/Desktop
    $ python3 -m pip --version
    pip 9.0.1 from /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
    (Intro-to-Pandas) main@McCarter:~/Desktop
    $ python3 -m pip install ipykernel
```

After which I receive errors which I root down to being an issue with installing tornado. SO I try installing tornado with pip and sudo apt install. I even try installing the infamous anaconda, a program who's developers I am sure take great pride in their software destroying all paths and being akin to the Manhattan project to set up:

```
(Intro-to-Pandas) main@McCarter:~/Desktop
$ python3 -m pip install ipykernel
Collecting ipykernel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/b0/f0be5c5ab335196f5cce96e5b889a4fcf5bfe462eb0acc05cd7e2caf65eb/ipykernel-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tornado>=4.2 (from ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/7f/8109821ff9df1bf3519169e34646705c32ac13be6a4d51a79ed57f47686e/tornado-6.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting traitlets>=4.1.0 (from ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d6/abcb22de61d78e2fc3959c964628a5771e47e7cc60d53e9342e21ed6cc9a/traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-client (from ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/c3/3043fe9ffd140d03c9d091a056794ccdc427c56ec19b8eea74f9ea0a498f/jupyter_client-5.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython>=5.0.0 (from ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/b5/ca080401b8dbde51a0f4377b4e22ce02b266340a1cda389b6dea702d06d1/ipython-7.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/88/0075e461560a1e750a0dcbf77f1d9de775028c37a19a346a6c565a257399/decorator-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython-genutils (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/bc/9bd3b5c2b4774d5f33b2d544f1460be9df7df2fe42f352135381c347c69a/ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from jupyter-client->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-core (from jupyter-client->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/44/065d2d7bae7bebc06f1dd70d23c36da8c50c0f08b4236716743d706762a8/jupyter_core-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyzmq>=13 (from jupyter-client->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/7a/9b98aabbde03fc4c5c38079ddec1331af3846d80c0b73bdb691a21adee9c/pyzmq-18.0.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/41/220f49aaea88bc6fa6cba8d05ecf24676326156c23b991e80b3f2fc24c77/pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pygments (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/e5/6d710c9cf96c31ac82657bcfb441df328b22df8564d58d0c4cd62612674c/Pygments-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backcall (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/71/c8ca4f5bb1e08401b916c68003acf0a0655df935d74d93bf3f3364b310e0/backcall-0.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting jedi>=0.10 (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/2b/1f188901be099d52d7b06f4d3b7cb9f8f09692c50697b139eaf6fa2928d8/jedi-0.13.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/a7/9b1dd14ef45345f186ef69d175bdd2491c40ab1dfa4b2b3e4352df719ed7/prompt_toolkit-2.0.9-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/e6/b5a1de8b0cc4e07ca1b305a4fcc3f9806025c1b651ea302646341222f88b/pexpect-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
Collecting parso>=0.3.0 (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/b1/522b2671cc6d134c9d3f5dfc0d02fee07cab848e908d03d2bffea78cca8f/parso-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9f/526a6947247599b084ee5232e4f9190a38f398d7300d866af3ab571a5bfe/wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/29/605c2cc68a9992d18dada28206eeada56ea4bd07a239669da41674648b6f/ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: tornado, backcall
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tornado ... error
  Complete output from command /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jgyop2hc/tornado/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpj4fqywe1pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for tornado
  Running setup.py clean for tornado
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for backcall ... error
  Complete output from command /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jgyop2hc/backcall/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmps7t3djcqpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for backcall
  Running setup.py clean for backcall
Failed to build tornado backcall
Installing collected packages: tornado, decorator, six, ipython-genutils, traitlets, python-dateutil, jupyter-core, pyzmq, jupyter-client, pickleshare, pygments, backcall, parso, jedi, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, ptyprocess, pexpect, ipython, ipykernel
  Running setup.py install for tornado ... error
    Complete output from command /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jgyop2hc/tornado/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-j9jy0w7y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/include/site/python3.5/tornado:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/wsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/log.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/options.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/curl_httpclient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/web.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/netutil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/http1connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/locale.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/concurrent.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/_locale_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/ioloop.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/iostream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/websocket.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/auth.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/httputil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/httpserver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/tcpserver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/tcpclient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/autoreload.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/httpclient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/template.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/locks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/queues.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/escape.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/simple_httpclient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/routing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    copying tornado/gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/log_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/tcpserver_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/locale_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/resolve_test_helper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/httpserver_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/import_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/util_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/escape_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/iostream_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/simple_httpclient_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/template_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/locks_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/routing_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/queues_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/options_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/testing_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/wsgi_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/netutil_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/runtests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/gen_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/twisted_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/curl_httpclient_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/asyncio_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/websocket_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/ioloop_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/concurrent_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/tcpclient_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/windows_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/httpclient_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/process_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/auth_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/autoreload_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/httputil_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/web_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/http1connection_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/platform/twisted.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/platform/caresresolver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/platform/interface.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/platform/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/platform/windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/platform/posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/platform/auto.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/platform/asyncio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/platform
    copying tornado/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/csv_translations
    copying tornado/test/csv_translations/fr_FR.csv -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/csv_translations
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/gettext_translations
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/gettext_translations/fr_FR
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/gettext_translations/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES
    copying tornado/test/gettext_translations/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/tornado_test.mo -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/gettext_translations/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES
    copying tornado/test/gettext_translations/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/tornado_test.po -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/gettext_translations/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES
    copying tornado/test/options_test.cfg -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/options_test_types.cfg -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/options_test_types_str.cfg -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/static
    copying tornado/test/static/robots.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/static
    copying tornado/test/static/sample.xml -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/static
    copying tornado/test/static/sample.xml.gz -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/static
    copying tornado/test/static/sample.xml.bz2 -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/static
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/static/dir
    copying tornado/test/static/dir/index.html -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/static/dir
    copying tornado/test/static_foo.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/templates
    copying tornado/test/templates/utf8.html -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test/templates
    copying tornado/test/test.crt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    copying tornado/test/test.key -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/test
    running build_ext
    building 'tornado.speedups' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c tornado/speedups.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/tornado/speedups.o
    tornado/speedups.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    /tmp/pip-build-jgyop2hc/tornado/setup.py:104: UserWarning:
    ********************************************************************
    WARNING: The tornado.speedups extension module could not
    be compiled. No C extensions are essential for Tornado to run,
    although they do result in significant speed improvements for
    websockets.
    The output above this warning shows how the compilation failed.

    Here are some hints for popular operating systems:

    If you are seeing this message on Linux you probably need to
    install GCC and/or the Python development package for your
    version of Python.

    Debian and Ubuntu users should issue the following command:

        $ sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev

    RedHat and CentOS users should issue the following command:

        $ sudo yum install gcc python-devel

    Fedora users should issue the following command:

        $ sudo dnf install gcc python-devel

    MacOS users should run:

        $ xcode-select --install

    ********************************************************************

      "The output above "
    running install_lib
    creating /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado
    error: could not create '/Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jgyop2hc/tornado/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-j9jy0w7y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/include/site/python3.5/tornado" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jgyop2hc/tornado/
```

I know this has something to do with tornado.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install ipykernel
The directory '/home/main/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/main/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting ipykernel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/b0/f0be5c5ab335196f5cce96e5b889a4fcf5bfe462eb0acc05cd7e2caf65eb/ipykernel-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (113kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting ipython>=5.0.0 (from ipykernel)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/b5/ca080401b8dbde51a0f4377b4e22ce02b266340a1cda389b6dea702d06d1/ipython-7.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (769kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 778kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting tornado>=4.2 (from ipykernel)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/7f/8109821ff9df1bf3519169e34646705c32ac13be6a4d51a79ed57f47686e/tornado-6.0.1.tar.gz (481kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 491kB 1.5MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sr9q5mjc/tornado/
```

I know I may have to buy a new computer and maybe move to another state after installing anaconda to get this to work.

```
$ pip install tornado
Collecting tornado
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/7f/8109821ff9df1bf3519169e34646705c32ac13be6a4d51a79ed57f47686e/tornado-6.0.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: tornado
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tornado ... error
  Complete output from command /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ccief454/tornado/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpg_2iu1zvpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for tornado
```

I also sudo apt install'd python-dev and buildessentials. Still did not help.

I just want to know why it's not working - for the sack of knowing.

```
Command "/Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-h1d5rcar/tornado/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ift0i4ks-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Documents/Intro-to-Pandas/include/site/python3.5/tornado" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-h1d5rcar/tornado/
(Intro-to-Pandas) main@McCarter:~/Desktop
$ sudo pip install tornado
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
(Intro-to-Pandas) main@McCarter:~/Desktop
$ sudo pip -m install tornado
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
(Intro-to-Pandas) main@McCarter:~/Desktop
```

Comment: So nothing lol? Should I Just reinstall everything [which in its own way is kind of really fucked up

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue(s).

```
/* Create a python3 virtual enviroment and then using jupyter notebook.*/
$ sudo python3 -m pip install virtualenv :
$ virtualenv mypythonAMCO : //create
$ source mypython/bin/activate : //activate
$ pip install jupyter : //install jupyter
/*Whenever you would like to stop the Jupyter Notebook process, press CTRL+C, type    Y when prompted, and then hit ENTER to confirm.*/
```

I uninstalled anaconda and followed the above, making a virtualenv python environment so as to isolate my 'coding area' in that only the files/modules and version of python I wish will run and be implemented. Making a python virtual environment is very helpful for it gives you more control. I was able to use pip with 'python3 emphasis' to install pandas and start up jupyter notebook.